# I want to make Random number generator in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, math, random

So basically i want to do is accept two values

```
var a,b;
```

and then put them in max and min for random number generator

```
 let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

How do I get the values *10* and *1* be `var a and b;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<title> TEST </title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function random()
{
var a,b; 
a=parseInt(form.v1.value);
b=parseInt(form.v2.value);
}
```

I have made this code for accepting values now how to i input them into max and min for my random number generator

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do this.

For a real application though, it is important to validate the input of the user before using it in your code. For example you should check if the maximum is higher than the minimum, if no malicious code is inserted etc.

```js
    btn = document.getElementById("button");

    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      minInput = document.getElementById("min");
      maxInput = document.getElementById("max");

      min = Number(minInput.value);
      max = Number(maxInput.value);

      randomNumber = document.getElementById("random-number");

      randomNumber.textContent = Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
      );
    });
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Random number generator</h1>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-width: 300px">
      <label for="max">Type your minimum here</label>
      <input type="number" id="min" />
      <label for="min">Type your maximum here</label>
      <input type="number" id="max" />
      <button id="button">Generate random number</button>
      <h2 id="random-number" style="text-align: center">...</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```